phpMyAdmin Throws error when trying to browse certian tables
I am having an issue with phpmyadmin (v5.2.1 & but have tried v5.2.2-dev) running via wamp on my local machine.
Here's the problem:
On most tables, when l attempt to click browse l get this error:

If l control click browse, this is the window that pops up:

This problem only seems to affect database tables that are on my local machine, l've never seen this error when remotely connecting to databases via the same phpmyadmin install.
If I go into the dev tools > application > storage > clear site data
it will work for a single click. Same thing if l clear out my browser cache/cookies.
Things l've tried that haven't worked:

I've tried testing in other browsers and incognito mode.
I've tried analyzing, optimizing, repairing etc operations on all tables.
I've disabled all browser extensions.
I've tried downloading a fresh copy of phpmyadmin.
I've tried downloading a dev copy of phpmyadmin.
I've tried multiple versions of PHP (8.0 through 8.2)
I've tried recreating and repopulating a few of th affected tables in mysql.
I've re-ran the phpmyadmin-x.x.x/sql/create_tables.sql with a user and added the following to my config.inc.php file:

/* Storage database and tables */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';

Doesn't seem to matter if $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs'; is commented out or not.
Does anyone know what the heck is going on and how l can fix this? I have exhaustivly searched here on stackoverflow and tried other means to get a resolution for this but cannot seem to fix it.

This is a really odd problem. Could you look in your webserver error log to see if anything is reported there? Which database server and version are you connecting to?

Hello @IsaacBennetch, thank you for the response.
apache v: 2.4.46
Database: MariaDB 10.5.25
PHP v: 8.0.27
phpMyAdmin v: 5.2.1

When l get the error, this shows up in the console:
Failed to parse JSON: Unexpected token '<', "<div id="p"... is not valid JSON
After clearing out all of the logs, and restarting the server here's the only thing l get: https://pastebin.com/m5jjZftu

Hm, that log looks okay. Could you try the demo server (linked from https://demo.phpmyadmin.net or directly at https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master/ with username root and no password) to see if that causes the same problem for you?

Also, since you're using WAMP, sometimes it's hard to troubleshoot problems because it might not be directly related to phpMyAdmin but might have something to do with some of the other parts of the stack or the way they modify phpMyAdmin. You could try to re-install WAMP (making sure to save any important files and databases!) and/or ask the WAMP folks for advice directly.
